# How to show nested object value in Thymeleaf form

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have Book and Author entities that I would like to bind to html form (user will insert data for Book with authors and those data will be sent via html form to the mysql database). I do not know how to bind Book.authors.forename and Book.authors.surname values to my thymeleaf form.

**Book.java**

```java
@Entity
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private String isbn;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL) // to save author's data when adding book to db
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("books")
    @JoinTable(name = "author_book", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "author_id"))
    private Set<Author> authors = new HashSet<>();
```

**Author.java**

```java
@Entity
public class Author {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String forename;
    private String surname;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "authors", cascade = CascadeType.ALL) // look -> @ManyToMany in Book
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("authors")
    private Set<Book> books = new HashSet<>();
```

**BookController.java**

```java
(...)
@GetMapping("/book/add")
    public ModelAndView addGet() {
        ModelAndView m = new ModelAndView();
        m.addObject("book", new Book());
        m.setViewName("addBook");
        return m;
    }

    @PostMapping("/book/add")
    public ModelAndView addBook(Book book, BindingResult br) {
        ModelAndView m = new ModelAndView("redirect:/index");
        bookService.addBook(book);

        m.addObject("book", new Book());
        return m;
    }
```

**addBook.html**

```html
<form th:action="@{/book/add}" th:object="${book}" th:method="post">

    <label for="author_name"> Author_Name </label>
    <input th:field="*{author}" id="author_name" type="text">

    <label for="author_surname"> Author_Surn </label>
    <input th:field="*{author}" id="author_surname" type="text">

    <label for="title"> Title </label>
    <input th:field="*{title}" id="title" type="text">

    <label for="isbn"> ISBN </label>
    <input th:field="*{isbn}" id="isbn" type="text">

    <button type="submit"> Add</button>
</form>
```

Problem is in the author_name and author_surname label and input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this code only for view purpose......

```
<span th:each="authors,iterStat : ${student.authors}">
         <span th:text="${authors.forename}"/><th:block th:if="${!iterStat.last}">,</th:block>
</span>
```

according to your code it's a data entry form .but  for many-to-many relation   it's not a good decision for insert book table data with author name from same time....

you can save book data first than assign author name .....

for more help [click this link](http://juhahinkula.github.io/2016-07-16-crudboot-manytomany/)

Comment: Didn't know it will be that hard to do. I thought the best way to do that will be to add book's data + author's data in one html form. Now I'm thinking about changing my html layout and do what you have suggested - add book and book author's data separatly. I assume it is that hard because of those @ManyToMany relations right? Will it be also that hard to do if I change Set<Author> authors to just Author author in my Book.java class?

Comment: if you use One -to- many relationship then also first save author name...
then save book data and from the book data saving from you can select a author name...